# Changing the website-url to http://my.url#menuitem on click on menu item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a small website where I already implemented a JavaScript code to change to content of a div if an item in the menu bar is clicked. I know have the problem, that if someone refreshes the website, they are at the start-page again. I want to change this so the name of the menu item is added to the url with a `#` in front of it. Wikipedia does this in some way if you click on an item in the content-overview of an article.

My question is now how I can achieve this?

This is my current JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
        $('#menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#content').load(page);
        });
});
```

And this the menu part of my HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="./content/ueber_mich.html">Über mich</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/kinesiologie.html">Kinesiologie</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/koerbler_symbole.html">Körbler Symbole</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/energiearbeit.html">Energiearbeit</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/ernaehrungsberatung.html">Ernährungsberatung</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/diaetberatung.html">Diätberatung</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/food_coach.html">Food Coach</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/heilkraeuterberater.html">Heilkräuterberater</a></li>
                <li><a href="./content/heilkraeuterprodukte.html">Heilkräuterprodukte</a></li>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="./content/salben.html">Salben</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./content/oele.html">Öle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./content/pflege.html">Pflege</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./content/bad_dusche.html">Bad/Dusche</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./content/allerlei.html">Allerlei</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And sorry for the bad description, I have absolutely no idea how to call this.

Comment: [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-
At first add an attribute in the menu.

```
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
            <li data-btn-name="ueber_mich"><a href="./content/ueber_mich.html">Über mich</a></li>
            <li data-btn-name="kinesiologie"><a href="./content/kinesiologie.html">Kinesiologie</a></li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

At the time of clicking on the menu change the location hash of the page

```
 $(function() {
    $('#menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-btn-name');
            $('#content').load(page);
    });
 });
```

At the time of opening the page first time, load the content depending on the hash.

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
   if(window.location.hash){
         $('#content').load('./content/'+window.location.hash+'.html');
     }
 })
```

Comment: I had to modify the code a bit (adding the data-btn-name attribute to `a` instead of `li`; remove the first character of window.location.hash on a page load since it's a `#` which isn't included it the file). Otherwise it works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this if text name is same as file name:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                window.location.hash = $(this).text();// if you want to show text of the li
                console.log($(this).text());
                $('#content').load(page);
        });
});
```

Comment: As you may have noticed, the filenames are different to the titles.